# how can I pass parameter to laravel getAttribute when I am appending it

Tags: laravel, model, accessor

this is my laravel custom accessor which I am appending using

```
protected $appends = [leave_balances];

public function getLeaveBalancesAttribute() {
    // some code
}
```

I want to pass a parameter when I am calling this accessor like this

```
public function getLeaveBalancesAttribute($parameter) {
        // use $parameter here
}

$payslip = Payslip::find(1);
\Log::debug($payslip->leave_balances("PARAMETER"));
```

I have searched and found that it is not possible. please can some one provide any solution to this I need to pass this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

you dont append attribute unless you want it to act as an attribute,

you can just create a method since you are calling it like a method

in you Payslip model

```
public function leaveBalances( $params ) { 
    return $params
}
```

then you can use it like

```
$payslip = Payslip::find(1);
$payslip->leaveBalances("PARAMETER") // which output PARAMETER
```

Comment: I want to use it as both ways, i need it to append I am just asking for possible solutions that will work with it.

Comment: then add an accessor calling the method `leaveBalances`, but it wont make sense as you have to pass a parameter to use the method

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an Attribute, you can only use it like this (following your example:

```php
protected $appends = ['leave_balances'];

public function getLeaveBalancesAttribute()
{
    return 'Hi!';
}

$payslip = Payslip::find(1);

$value = $payslip->leave_balances;

dd($value); // This will output string(Hi!)
```

What you (I think) want is `setLeaveBalancesAttribute`, so you can pass a value and do whatever you want with it:

```php
public function setLeaveBalancesAttribute($parameter)
{
    return $parameter.' Yes!';
}

$payslip = Payslip::find(1);

$payslip->leave_balances = 'It works!';

dd($payslip->leave_balances); // This will output string(It works! Yes!)
```

But, if you are using Laravel 9+, please do use the [new way of defining attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), it is better.

Comment: well I don't want to use mutator I want to pass parameter in accessor.

Comment: You CAN'T pass a parameter in accessor... This is basic PHP, you either define an accesor, or a method, period.

Comment: well thanks for you answer! however I have already mentioned in my question that it is not possible I am just asking for work around.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to work around, you need to share a real example as we do not understand what you truly NEED, not what you want. If you want to call a method and get something back, there you go, a method (function), if you want to manipulate a "property", use attributes as I have shared. I do not understand what you NEED. And as I said, YOU CAN'T pass parameters to attributes, the only way is what I showed, else use a method...

Comment: public function getLeaveBalances($date = NULL) {
if ($date) {
// do something
}
}

Comment: if that method helps, what you want is a simple method as @silver shared... Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the attribute `$appends` in the model where you have the accessor. Something like this:

```
protected $appends = ['the name of accessor'];
```

However, it will be in the most, I think in all, the responses or query you do with the model you declare it.

Another options is creating a single instance of the model using the `::find` method. For example:

```
$model_instance = Model::find($id);
$attribute = $model_instance->attribute;
```

Here is the documentation reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor